# How to update a single field using EF4

Tags: entity-framework-4

I want to update a single field in my table for a particular row. I am using Entity Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

Options I can think of are:

- Using a Stored Procedure
- Direct connection to the database and using
  sql statement

I am not aware of any more efficient method to perform this task.

[EDIT]
I would like to do the update in the same operation as the Get for that row, so that it is done in one DB call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to complicate things. Just change the one property and `SaveChanges`. Unless you're doing something odd, that should only change the one column. Look at the SQL to verify.

Comment: Very good point, but how do I do it in the same operation as the Get call? I want to limit the DB call.

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimization to me.

Comment: "premature optimization," means to me that I should not worry about one call to DB right now, make it work and look at optimization at a later stage of development.

Comment: Almost. It means optimize the slowest part of your app (I'm betting this is not it), not look later.